# HTML: Box Model and Alignment

Tags: html, css

I am trying to learn HTML and CSS and I am a bit confused on how to achieve my desired result. I created divs allowing me to split the page into 6 columns. I am attempting to make a middle section that would hold four pieces of content and would have a border around the four pieces while the entire page would be split into 6 columns. This is an outline of my structure:

```
<div class = "myRow">
<div class = "col-2">
</div>
<div class = "col-8">
    <div class = "col-2">
        content
    </div>
    <div class = "col-2">
        content
    </div>
    <div class = "col-2">
        content
    </div>
    <div class = "col-2">
        content
    </div>
</div>
<div class = "col-2>
</div>
</div?
```

The col-2 has width set to 16.66% and col-8 has width set to 66.66%. The divs inside the col-8 are inline and centered. In my mind the boxes inside the col-8 div should take up the entire col-8. However, there is a lot of extra space to the right. I thought this was because the percentages for divs inside col-8 refer to col-8's size, so I switched the col-2 on the inside to col-3 (25%). However, now they take up too much space and they wrap around. Is this an issue with padding/margins/border not being included in width or is it something else? How do I fix it?

CSS:

```
div.myRow
{
width: 100%;
display: flex;
flex-wrap: wrap;
}

div.col-1
{
width: 8.33%;
}
div.col-2
{
width: 16.66%;
}
div.col-3
{
width: 25%;
}
div.col-4
{
width: 33.33%;
}
div.col-5
{
width: 41.66%;
}
div.col-6
{
width: 50%;
}
div.col-7
{
width: 58.33%;
}
div.col-8
{
width: 66.66%;
}
div.col-9
{
width: 75%%;
}
div.col-10
{
width: 83.33%;
}
div.col-11
{
width: 91.66%;
}
div.col-12
{
width: 100%;
}

*{
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
-moz box-sizing: border-box;
box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Comment: Are you splitting the page into 12 or 6 columns? Your question kind of says both.

Comment: I wrote divs for 12 to allow me to make the maximum number of combinations but my page only uses 6. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Also it would help if you included your CSS

Comment: ^^ and maybe a jsfiddle like this: http://jsfiddle.net/v4cxwuvx/ but with your css off course

Comment: _“Is this an issue with padding/margins/border not being included in width or is it something else?”_ – not sure (because your question lacks an example for a quick check), but yes, in the standard box model padding and border are included in width – but you can change that, using the `box-sizing` property.

Comment: Here is a detailed example: http://jsfiddle.net/ktlibert/vkkgctx5/

Comment: CBroe, I tried creating a new div to put inside the col-8 with width at 25% and box-sizing set to border-box which should include everything but margin. Then I set the margin to 0. However, the wrap around still happens. Am I overlooking something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `<div>`s you have are not taking up the space of the `col-8` because they are given the 16.66% width.

**CSS percentages**

Percentages in CSS are a calculation of an element with respect to its container. So your `col-2` `<div>`s are 16.66% x 4 = 66.64% of the `col-8`'s width.

You should also note, that your first `col-2` that you have is not within the `col-8` so it is going to take up 16.66% of ITS container, which is a different width entirely. This means changing your `col-2` width to 25% works for the `<div>` inside `col-8` but for the leftmost column that is outside of `col-8` it's going to take up 25% of the screen, thus throwing off your whole structure.

**Floating**

There is also some subtle spacing between elements unless you handle that or float the elements left, so you'll want to fix that as well.

```
float: left;
```

**Fix**

Changing the col-2 property as follows gives you a `col-2` element that takes up exactly 25% of its parent.

```
div.col-2
{
    width: 25%;
    float:left;
}
```

This means we'll want to rename or change the first `col-2` because we don't want a leftmost column taking up 25% of the page:

```
<div class="myRow">
<!-- Change this col-2 to something else. col-2 now takes up 25% of its container -->
    <div align="center" class="co-1">
    </div>
    <div class="col-8" style = "border-style: solid; border-color: black">
...
```

And a working [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vkkgctx5/2/) if it helps

Comment: When I change it to col-3 (25%) shouldn't it work? For some reason it takes up too much space when I do that. Also, I do have inline in my actual code check the jsfiddle link in the comments. I should have included it in my example.

Comment: @klib actually, on second thought. It looks like your fix is to just float the elements left in col-2. `width: 25%;     float: left;`

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the box-sizing property on your troublesome columns to border-box like so:

```
box-sizing: border-box;
```

This will include the width of any border or padding to your indicated width.  Also be sure to clear any margins could be inherited.

```
margin: 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is what you are looking for:

```
.col-2 {
    width:16%;
    text-align:center;
    display: inline-block;
}
.col-8 {
    display: inline;
}

.myRow {
    text-align:center;
}
```

When you put 16% for `col-2` and 66% for `col-8`, it will try to set the width of your blocks inside `col-6` to 16% x 66% = 11.1% of the whole parent's width. As a result, the width of your `div`s inside `col-8` will be different than the ones outside.

Here is the link to a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/5jgkpscw/3/